# Gridview: Sql Update statement "Where RowID=Current editing row number" , how to set it in update statment?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a simple gridview and sqldatasource to bind data from datatable to gridview.

- // "Column" is a column , type : int , increment by one , primary key

// ID is just a column type int 
Here is my code in row updating event:

```
 string con = "conn string";

            string sqlQuery = "Update TableName set Column = @Column WHERE RowID = '1' (//here I need to get the current editing row number)";
            using (SqlConnection dataConnection = new SqlConnection(con))
            {
                using (SqlCommand dataCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, dataConnection))
                {
                    int vas = 121;
                    dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Column", vas);
                    dataConnection.Open();
                    dataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    dataConnection.Close();

                }

            }
```

Here are my questions:

1.For this code :     string sqlQuery = "UPDATE mytable SET ID = '131' WHERE No = '1' ";

- I dont want to set the No fixed , I want to set like this
  No=CurrentEditingRowNumber but I don't know how can I do that and
  make it work.
- I know how to get the current editing ( think so ) :  GridViewRow row
  = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
- But I don't know how to use it in the update statment

2.For the code above if I open it in browser and let's say there are 2 rows ( 1 and 2 ) and my code says to update if No = 1 .

If press Update to the first row nothing happens but if I press update from the second row then the code is executing on the first row as it was coded.. how can I fix that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use CommandArgument and get that value in Gridview onrowcommand event.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("RowID")%>' CommandName="btnUpdate" Text="Update">

  protected void GridView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {
    if(e.CommandName=="btnUpdate")
    {
      int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
      string sqlQuery = "Update TableName set Column = @Column WHERE RowID = index;
      //now bind your gridview here using index id.
    }
  }
```

Comment: What's with the link button because I don't have one , do you mean the update button from the gridview?

Comment: exactly, use Button if you want but the idea is getting rowID.

Comment: I did this : http://pastebin.com/fMvriWdD , but..I can only set the value to the first row and when I press the edit button then the update button nothing happens but when I press the edit button from the second row I can see the value changed in the first row but..that's wrong

Comment: breakpoint and check whether you are going inside Command Event and getting rowId.

Comment: I never understood how to work with the breakpoint , so I set the breakpoint where? and then?

Comment: If you really don't know how to use breakpoint then surely missing a lot, learn today I recommend. go to this linK: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/21/vs-2010-debugger-improvements-breakpoints-datatips-import-export.aspx and http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Debuging-Breakpoints.aspx

Comment: thank you I will learn it later but now I really need to make this work because I don't have so much time and I need to send it to someone. what can I do with my code? I think something is wrong..

Comment: If you couldn't get what I have mention in my answer then you need to follow this flow, very simple example is given here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx, but what you need is enough in my answer I guess

Comment: Hey! you should really need to bind Gridview after dataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); in your code in order to get changed value: 
        GridView1.DataSource = dataTable;//or dataset, datareader
        GridView1.DataBind();   use this link: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/john_charles/data-binding-in-Asp-Net-2-0-using-gridview-control/

Comment: ..I said I've tried but .it didn't worked..take a look at the paste.bin code please

Comment: I saw you are missing to bind gridview: GridView1.DataSource = dataTable;//or dataset, datareader GridView1.DataBind();

Comment: k I added these under conneciton close :       DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    GridView1.DataSource = ds;

                    GridView1.DataBind();  and I get Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'.  Remove one definition. at databind

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the update id into your gridview setting. Here I give you small demo

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnEdit" runat="server" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" ToolTip="Edit Record" ImageUrl="~/images/edit.gif" OnClick="imgEdit_OnClick" />
```

and Onclick event you perform your operation

```
 protected void imgEdit_OnClick(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton im1 = (ImageButton)sender;
        GridViewRow grv1 = (GridViewRow)im1.Parent.Parent;
        string id = grv1.Cells[0].Text.ToString();
        // pass this Id value into your query string for update operation. better way you follow three-tier architecture.
    }
```

if you want anything else you can reply here.